# Cannot ssh to or from Raspberry PI 3

Tags: wifi, ssh

I'm using a new raspbian image (Jessie). I tried both lite and normal. Wifi connection is ok, I can browse the web and ping with no problems.

Starting an SSH connection (either from RPi3 to a Linux box or from the Linux Box to RPi3) starts ok. Connection is established, it asks for the user, then the password. After that it's stuck. The window is frozen and the prompt never appears.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Past the  output into the question.

Comment: Paste the output of `ssh -v` - that will enable verbose mode which might help clarify where it's getting stuck.

Comment: Try ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no pi@raspberrypi

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately even though adding "-o GSSAPIAuthentication=no" eliminates a couple of messages in the terminal when "-v" is added to the command line, the final result is the same.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh -v -o GSSAPIauthentication=no root@172.16.3.1
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.3.1 [172.16.3.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Comment: debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1

Comment: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT

Comment: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1f:23:91:a3:eb:9f:14:2b:35:9c:15:0a:e1:d0:df:d8
debug1: Host '172.16.3.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

Comment: debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@172.16.3.1's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 172.16.3.1 ([172.16.3.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = es_AR.UTF-8

Comment: Sorry for the format! I just couldn't find how to attach a file!

Comment: I think you can use backquotes (as if you were formatting code), but that may not work in comments, I don't know.

Comment: @Daniel, you simply edit and add it to your original post! (As shown above, it is totally unreadable!)

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information from the output of `ssh -v` I can think of two things:

1. You have another machine on the same subnet with the same IP address. This could be because your DHCP server / cablebox / whatever is borked, or because you have given a static IP address to that other machine. To diagnose this, make a note of the IP address and the MAC address of your Pi (`ifconfig -a` shows you all the interfaces and their addresses) and turn it off. Now go to some other machine, make sure there is no ARP entry for the Pi you just turned off (`sudo arp -an`; if you see the IP address or the MAC address there, use `sudo arp -d` to remove that entry. Now ping again. If you get a response, it means that I was right and there was a machine with a duplicate address on your network.
2. You could have some strange settings in your ssh config files. Remove them (well, move them out of the way), and try again.

If neither helps, make sure you give us the output of `ssh -v` just like another responder suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately the IP is unique. "ping <RPI3 IP>" from other machine answers. Turned RPI3 off -> stopped answering. Flushed arp cache (arp -d <RPI3 IP>). Ping again -> now answer nor MAC entry in ARP table. Turn RP3 on again -> answer and MAC entry. I attached ssh -v output in the previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: When you lose ssh connectivity between the Pi and your other machine, can you still ping the pi / start a new ssh connection?

Here is another debugging suggestion. On your pi, from the console (so, not ssh-ed), run `tcpdump -n -i eth0 -s 1500 -X -v -v not port 22 > traces1` and `tcpdump -n -i eth0 -v -v port 22 > traces2` in the background. When the connection dies, look at the packet traces to see if you can identify something, such as lots of packets suddenly being transmitted, a spurious TCP RST to port 22, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your output above you are missing your keys file/folder.
I wrote a simple script to handle this as I am constantly nuke paving my setups.

Try this script out. You can place it in your user folder and run as sudo.
If you don't need a root key just don't set one, it will gracefully exit and not set it up for root.

You need to generate and enter your keys in the auth variables up top.

chmod this to be executable.

```
chmod 0777 <name_of_script>
```

Run it with no args to see the help display.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## non-root username
user='pi'
auth_key_user=''
auth_key_root=''

#### No need to edit anything below ####

ulimit -c unlimited
case "$1" in

auth){
    if [ $USER = "root" ]; then
        usersize=${#auth_key_user}
        rootsize=${#auth_key_root}
        if grep "$auth_key_user" "/home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" > /dev/null && [[ ( "$usersize" > 10 ) ]]
        then
            echo user key exists
        else
            if [[ ( "$usersize" < 1 ) ]]
            then
                echo Can\'t apply an empty key. You need to enter one in the script.
            else
                if [ ! -f /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys ]; then
                    mkdir /home/$user/ssh
                    mv /home/$user/ssh /home/$user/.ssh
                fi
                echo user key doesn\'t exist, writing it.
                echo $'\r' >> /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
                echo $auth_key_user >> /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
                chmod 0755 /home/$user/.ssh
                chmod 0644 /home/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys
                chown -R $user:$user /home/$user/.ssh
            fi
        fi
        if grep "$auth_key_root" "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys" > /dev/null && [[ ( "$rootsize" > 10 ) ]]
        then
            echo root key exists
        else
            if [[ ( "$rootsize" < 1 ) ]]
            then
                echo Can\'t apply an empty key. You need to enter one in the script.
            else
                if [ ! -f /root/.ssh/authorized_keys ]; then
                    mkdir /root/ssh
                    mv /root/ssh /root/.ssh
                fi
                echo root key doesn\'t exist, writing it.
                echo $'\r' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
                echo $auth_key_root >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo This needs you to run the script as sudo or root...
        exit 1
    fi
}
;;

help|*){
    printf "\n"
    printf " Usage: \t$0 [$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)help$(tput sgr0)|$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)auth$(tput sgr0)]\r\n"
    printf "\n"
    printf " $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)auth$(tput sgr0)\t\tSets your ssh authorized keys if you entered them in this script.\n"
    printf " $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)help$(tput sgr0)\t\tDisplays this guide.\n"
    printf "\n"
}
;;

esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that `ntpd` kills the network on my RPi 3, in syslog.

Think this describes it, [NTP time check freezes network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=104904).

Comment: I cannot think of a mechanism by which ntpd would kill the network. There is no real time clock on the Pi, so it's not like some bug could be triggered by writing to the rtc register(s) (at least I _think_ there is no RTC; if it exists, it has no entry anywhere in /sys). 

Unless  what is being interpreted as the network dying is ntpd going into a tight loop, flooding the network with back-to-back packets, but that should be easy to check with tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that the basic configuration is correct- go to 
Menu >> Preferences >> Raspberry Pi Configuration >> Interfaces tab. Then check if SSH is Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=138631&start=75 describing your problem, if you can ssh via cable, but not via wifi.
The solution is described at the end of page 4 of the thread:

Add the line

```
IPQoS cs0 cs0
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart the daemon (or the raspi).

```
sudo service ssh restart
```